# What is the purpose of "#if 0 ...#endif" declaration

Tags: c, if-statement, directive

now I'm confused again.
In our old C-code I've found some strange parts, a dump function that seems to print to terminal and I wonder if you can explain why this "#if 0" is used?

My guess is that this is an old way to comment out code....

```
#if 0
dump(b, cnt)
     char *b;
     int cnt;
{
  int i;

  if (cnt == 0)
    return;

  for (i=0; i < cnt; i++, b++){
    if ((i % 16) == 0)
      printf("\n");
    printf("0x%02x ", *b);
  }
}
#endif
```

Comment: It allows you to easily enable/disable a piece of code (for example, for testing purposes).

Comment: And you need to consider that is not equivalent to commenting.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an "old way", it's a separate way. This uses the preprocessor to cut out the contained lines, so the compiler never sees them.

It's an extreme form of "feature toggles"; often you see code like

```
#if defined SOME_HANDY_FEATURE
void use_some_handy_feature(int handyness)
{
  ...
}
#endif
```

But here the `#define` is replaced by the literal `0` which is of course false, so the code block is removed.

It's handy since it works even if the removed code contains comments, which normal `/* ... */` comments don't since they don't nest.

Comment: Thanks guys, my hunch was right then. Sorry that I missed it had been asked before ;( my misstake.